# How do I create a new canvas for each drawn object referenced by the Adapter?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-canvas, android-adapter, android-gridview

I am trying to get my getView method to work in my canvasAdapter.java class with my custom view class. I was trying to reimplement the imageView example I have gotten from https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html. Here is my canvasAdapter.java class.

```java
public class CanvasAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public Context getmContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    private Context mContext;
    
    private AttributeSet attributeSet = new AttributeSet() {...};
    
    private Random randInt = new Random();

    public CanvasAdapter(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyCanvas dummyCanvas = new MyCanvas(mContext, attributeSet);
        if(convertView == null){
            dummyCanvas.clearCanvas();
        }
        for (Integer[] row: mThumbIds) {
            for (Integer ele: row) {
                ele = position;   
            }            
        }

        return dummyCanvas;
    }

    // Keep all canvas objects in array
    public Integer[][] mThumbIds = {   // random values
            { randInt.nextInt(3), randInt.nextInt(3) },
            { randInt.nextInt(3), randInt.nextInt(3) },
            { randInt.nextInt(3), randInt.nextInt(3) },
            { randInt.nextInt(3), randInt.nextInt(3) },
            { randInt.nextInt(3), randInt.nextInt(3) },
            { randInt.nextInt(3), randInt.nextInt(3) },
            { randInt.nextInt(3), randInt.nextInt(3) },
            { randInt.nextInt(3), randInt.nextInt(3) }
    };
}
```

I am trying to get getView to work with MyCanvas:

```java
public class MyCanvas extends View {
    private Paint pixelPaint;

    public Bitmap getMyBitmap() {
        return myBitmap;
    }

    private Paint myBitMapPaint;
    public Bitmap myBitmap;
    private Canvas myCanvas;

    CanvasAdapter canvasAdapter = new CanvasAdapter( getContext() );

    private Random randInt = new Random();

    public MyCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        myBitMapPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        pixelPaint = new Paint();
        pixelPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        pixelPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        pixelPaint.setColor(pixelPaintColor);
        pixelPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        pixelPaint.setStrokeWidth(42);
    }

    ...

    Integer[][] shapePosition = canvasAdapter.mThumbIds;
    int shapeheight = 1;
    int shapewidth = 1;

    public void drawShapes()  // fill in grid
    {
        for(int row = 0; row < shapePosition.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < shapePosition[row].length; col++){
                switch(shapePosition[row][col])
                {
                    case 0: pixelPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                        pixelPaint.setStrokeWidth(60);
                        myCanvas.drawCircle(row*shapeheight + 0.5f, col*shapewidth + 0, 0.5f, pixelPaint);
                    case 1: pixelPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        myCanvas.drawRect(row*shapeheight + 0.1f,col*shapewidth + 0.1f, row*shapeheight + 0.9f, col*shapewidth + 0.9f, pixelPaint);
                    case 2: pixelPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        myCanvas.drawRect(row*shapeheight + 0.1f,col*shapewidth + 0.1f, row*shapeheight + 0.9f, col*shapewidth + 0.9f, pixelPaint);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearCanvas() {
        myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int w = myBitmap.getWidth();
        int h = myBitmap.getHeight();

        drawShapes();

        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0 ,0, myBitMapPaint);
    }
}
```

I think what confuses me the MyCanvas logic inside of the getView. I know I want the canvas drawn objects to be in the positions set in the View. I just don't know how to do that.
Also, I have an error in main activity class.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        //gridview.setAdapter(new CanvasAdapter(this));
        GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        CanvasAdapter canvasAdapterAdapter = new CanvasAdapter(this);
        gridView.setAdapter(canvasAdapterAdapter);
    }
}
```

Error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.midterm, PID: 17880
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.midterm.CanvasAdapter$1 cannot be cast to android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser

Comment: MyCanvas extend View? This is not a canvas

Comment: @Style-7 You are correct, but I am trying to use gridview with canvas. I am not sure if I exactly need the getView method for my purpose. I was just following the tutorial example.